# java displaying arraylist to textfield

Tags: java, arraylist

displaying arraylist values in text field not working;this class contains savebutton when it will save foodquan++ in to the list,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;    
/**
 *
 * @author sirak elec
 */
public class User extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 int Food_num;
 int Food_quan;
 int Drink_num;
 int Drink_quan;
 int Tab_num;
 ArrayList saveArray1=new ArrayList(); 


   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   Tab_num =Integer.parseInt(Text3.getText());
   Food_num =Integer.parseInt(Text6.getText());
   Food_quan =Integer.parseInt(Text7.getText());
   Drink_num =Integer.parseInt(Text10.getText());
   Drink_quan =Integer.parseInt(Text11.getText());
   if((Tab_num!=0)&&(Food_quan<=10)&&(Drink_num<=10)&&(Drink_quan<=10)&&(Food_num<=10)){
   String ord ="Order Succesfull";  
   Text14.setText(ord);
    }
  else{
    String tryagain ="Invalid Entry";  
   Text14.setText(tryagain);  
  }
    }                                       

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 show();
    } 
public void show(){
     User cquantity=new User();
     int c=cquantity.getquancakesold();
     saveArray1.add(c);

    }                                       
public int getquancakesold(){
return Food_quan++;
}
}
```

in this class when show button is pressed it will display the values in the arraylist to a textfield,this was the goal

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.List;
public class Staff extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
     User val=new User();
     list t=val.saveArray1;
     if(val.Food_num==1){
         for (int j=0;j<t.size();j++) {
             jTextField5.setText((t.get(i));
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: i'm new to oop can you explain alittle more

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the `JTextField` value each time you call `setText()`.  You need to build the `String` value in the loop and then call `setText()` with the created `String`.